# Prestashop product listing page not showing until i refresh the browser

Tags: jquery, prestashop, product

I have having a very strange problem that i cant figure out whats the causes and how to solve it.

http://goo.gl/GUUUCI

this is the url if you go you will see all products are showing but if press 2nd page in bottom navigation then nothing is showing. but if you refresh the page then everything will show. this this happens with every onclick change event for example if you select A-Z sorting or any other from drop down nothing is showing correctly until you refresh the browser can any one help?

Comment: Well there is definitely something fishy with your javascript, but we'll need some code to help

Comment: Hi, I don't know which one is making it behave like this. Can you please suggest which code I should post?

Comment: Your web site seems to work perfectly fine now. I stumbled across this page, as I'm too experiencing the same problem. Could I please ask how you solved it? Apologies for the hassle, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Block Layered Navigation Module.

I believe this is causing your problem. Well, it certainly did for us.